# convergence of a sequence with strict inequality condition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $(u_n)$ be the sequence defined by $u_0 > 0$ and $u_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(u_n + v_n)$ where $v_n$ is another sequence such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $v_n < u_n$. This sequence is nonincreasing and lower bounded, thus it admits a limit. The limit is $0$ for a fair amount of examples i've tried but i am struggling to show that it is the case for any such $v_n$. The result holds under the additional assumption that $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{v_n}{u_n} < 1$. Does it hold in general?

Comment: Hint: if $u_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(u_n + v_n)$ with $u_n \to 0$ then $u_{n+1}' = \frac{1}{2}(u_n' + v_n')$ but $u_n' \to 1$, where $u_n'=u_n+1$ and $v_n'=v_n+1 \lt u_n'$, so the result does not hold in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $v_n=u_n-a_n$ with $a_n>0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ convergent. Then $u_{n+1}=u_n-\dfrac{a_n}{2}$ and so
$$
u_n=u_0-\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{a_m}{2}\to u_0-\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n.
$$

Answer (score 5):

The conjecture is certainly not true, since one can take any decreasing sequence $\{u_n\}$ and simply define $v_n = 2u_{n+1}-u_n$. For example, if $u_n = 1 + \frac1n$ and $v_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n+1}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = 1$.

For that matter, one can always add a constant to $u_n$ and $v_n$ simultaneously while preserving the assumptions, so the limit $0$ is not special at all.